# Read Event Log file (.evt) using C# throw Data is not valid

Tags: c#, event-log

I try read a Event Log file **.evt** file from C#, and using a filter to only get the **Framework 2.0** entries:

```
string query = "*[System/Provider/@Name=\"ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0\"]"; 

var elQuery = new EventLogQuery("C:\evento.evt", PathType.FilePath, query);
var elReader = new System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader(elQuery);

List<EventRecord> eventList = new List<EventRecord>();

for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent(); null != eventInstance; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
{
    string source = eventInstance.ProviderName;

    eventList.Add(eventInstance);
    if (eventInstance.Properties.Count > 3)
    {
        string dateTime = eventInstance.Properties[2].Value.ToString(); 
        string message = eventInstance.Properties[1].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint, I see correct result for a few of Event Log entries, but if I press F5, **elReader.ReadEvent()** throw the error **Data is not valid**

Any Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a `for` loop, the condition is not checked until *after* the iteration.
So here, `elReader.ReadEvent()` will return `null`, and set that in `eventInstance`. Then the loop body will run, *then* it will check if `eventInstance` is `null` and stop.

The normal way to do this sort of read until null loop is to use a `while` loop instead, where you set the variable and check the condition at the same time:

```
while ((EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
{
  // as before
}
```

This will set `eventInstance` from `ReadEvent()` as before, but check if that returned `null` *before* running the body of the loop.

The classic other place this pattern is used in .NET is reading lines in a text file, e.g. see this [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/94223t4d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

public static void LeerPrint()
{

```
        string logType = "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational";
        string query = "*[System/EventID=307]";

        var elQuery = new
            EventLogQuery(logType, PathType.LogName, query);
        var elReader = new EventLogReader(elQuery);

        for (EventRecord eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent(); eventInstance != null; eventInstance = elReader.ReadEvent())
        {
            string source = eventInstance.ProviderName;
            Class1.WriteLog("1:"+eventInstance.Properties[1].Value.ToString() , config.validadirectorio());
            Class1.WriteLog("2:" + eventInstance.Properties[2].Value.ToString(), config.validadirectorio());
            Class1.WriteLog("3:" + eventInstance.Properties[3].Value.ToString(), config.validadirectorio());
            Class1.WriteLog("4:" + eventInstance.Properties[4].Value.ToString(), config.validadirectorio());
            Class1.WriteLog("5:" + eventInstance.Properties[5].Value.ToString(), config.validadirectorio());
            Class1.WriteLog("6:" + eventInstance.Properties[6].Value.ToString(), config.validadirectorio());
            Class1.WriteLog("7:" + eventInstance.Properties[7].Value.ToString(), config.validadirectorio());

            
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks for your answer. This could be improved by adding details of **how/why this addresses the problem in the question**. Try to remember, you aren't solving one person's problem here and now, but for all users of all time who might stumble upon this question. Details are important!